# Hour Series to Matrix in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert an hourly `Pandas Series` into a `DataFrame` as a `DataFrame` indexed only with the date and each hour as a column.

For example, let's say I have this Series:

```
YEAR = 2017
serie = pd.Series(pd.date_range(
        start=f'{YEAR}-01-01', end=f'{YEAR}-12-31 23:00:00', freq='H'))
```

But I want it like:

```
                             h01      h02      h03     h04     h05  ...
Date
2017-01-01                   data    data     data     data   data  ...
```

Comment: What are values `1         2       3       4       5` ?

Comment: Probably 01:00:00 converts to 1, 02:00:00 to 2 and so on

Comment: They are simply data. I'm changing them for possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `Series` is with `DatetimeIndex` and filled some data.

Then need [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns created by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) and [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one columns `DataFrame`:

```
YEAR = 2017
serie = pd.Series(np.arange(8760), pd.date_range(
        start=f'{YEAR}-01-01', end=f'{YEAR}-12-31 23:00:00', freq='H'))

df = serie.to_frame('vals').assign(date = lambda x: x.index.date,
                                   hour = lambda x: x.index.strftime('h%H'))
#print (df)


df1 = df.pivot('date','hour','vals')
#print (df1)
```

Another solution:

```
serie.index = [serie.index.date, serie.index.strftime('h%H')]
df1 = serie.unstack()
```